# Maximum number of pages you can aggregate via Facebook Insights API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-insights

Do you if there is a limit in the number of pages you can aggregate via Facebook insights api? 
eg. Aggregate all fans from 30 facebook pages from the same brand for example?

Thanks!
Jeremie